# JavaScript regular expression to validate input such as 2.4**6-0

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to validate a line of input. it should be one or more integers. The integers can be separated by a single full stop or one or more asterisks. 0 is not valid, but -0 is. A full stop is not valid at the end of the line, but one or more asterisks are. So "2.4*-2.-0**" is valid.

I have tried using:

```
/^(?:(?:-0)|(?:-?[1-9]\d*)\.|\*+)*(?:(?:-0)|(?:-?[1-9]\d*))\**$/.test(myline)
```

but this rejects input that has a mix of full stops and asterisks in it.

I do subsequently successfully parse out all the components of the string using:

```
var regEx = new RegExp("((?:-0)|(?:-?[1-9]\\d*))(\\.|\\*+|$)", "g"), result;
while((result = regEx.exec(myline)) !== null)
```

I could concatenate the values of `result[0]` and `result[1]` from each pass of the while loop and at the end compare that with the original string. I was just hoping for a single test at the start before entering the loop with all its logic.

Comment: What do you mean by "single full stop?"

Comment: Too many conditions, especially `-0` is not valid. Btw, a decimal point in any location in a number is a valid number, therefore a digit plus dot at end of the input is valid.

Comment: Given the number of conditions you'd be better off writing a simple parser for this. It wouldn't be too difficult.

Comment: By single full stop I meant 2.4.6****8 is valid but 2..6 is not valid. -0 is valid in this context, perhaps I should not have said integers. I mean a series of numeric digits that can be preceded by a minus sign, leading zeros are not valid, nor is a leading plus sign for my validation requirements.

Comment: @SteveWaring Apologies for seeming dense, but I'm still not clear on what in your sample string constitutes a "single full stop." A period? Two periods?

Comment: A single period. 2.4 is valid. 2**4 is valid. 2..4 is not valid. 2. is not valid. 2* is valid.

Comment: Ahh okay, thanks :)

Comment: How come `2*` is valid but `2.` is not, if both `*` and `.` are used for separating numbers? Why is multiple `*`'s valid? Could you give more correct and wrong examples?

Comment: i don't really see why the reason for the verification rules is relevant. But if you must know, the input is an instruction for a Chrome extension that injects script into the frames on a page to paste or select from a drop down individual characters from a password acquired from the clipboard. Asterisks, indicate to automatically advance to the next valid input field in the page's DOM. Periods indicate the user will select the next input field and instruct the extension to continue with a command key. If there are any bits of my validation rule that are unclear please ask.

Comment: It's not that I needed a reason. But it helps solving the problem, by understanding the problem.

Comment: @SteveWaring I don't believe anyone was asking for the "why." Vallentin was asking for a better definition. Examples of what counts as valid, what doesn't, etc. It also helps to understand the problem if some context is given.

Comment: All these are valid: "2", "2*", "2**********", "1.2.3*4*5*6****7.8.-2****-0", "-0" These are not valid "Fred", "2..3", "2.", "01", "0.1", "0", "2 Fred", "2 ", "Fred 2", "Fred2",

Comment: Please see the additional information I have added to the original question.

Comment: Leading zeroes are not valid, yet -0 is valid? What about -00, or -000 etc?

Comment: "-00" "-02" "-" are all invalid. Or, to quote Wikipedia "A leading zero is any 0 digit that comes before the first nonzero digit in a number string in positional notation. For example, James Bond's famous identifier, 007, has two leading zeros."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer may be to test for invalid things rather than a completely valid string, such as:

```
if (/(?:[^-.*0-9])|(?:^[.*0])|(?:\d-)|(?:\.[.*])|(?:\*\.)|(?:[.*]-?0\d)|(?:[-.]$)|(?:-00)|(?:-[^0-9])|(?:[.*]0)|^$/.test(mydata))
```

I have run a comprehensive set of test cases through this and have not found any problems.